# URLWithString removes part of NSString path

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I'm having trouble parsing a csv file with CHCSVParser. My csv file doesn't "satisfy the stream" I and think the problem is that the URL for the file is bad. I get the URL like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"csv"]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
```

When I log `path` I get this string:

```
/Users/wilhelmmichaelsen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/11F0BE77-9179-4A7B-B03E-1143957A8D02/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7FE0AD10-DE7A-4C6D-9EED-4A95F9C197AE/Climate.app/file.csv
```

When I log `url` I get this string:

```
/Users/wilhelmmichaelsen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/11F0BE77-9179-4A7B-B03E-1143957A8D02/data/Containers/Bu ... le.csv
```

It seems like the path string is being shortened (...). Is this something strange and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you want a URL, don't use `pathForResource:ofType:`. Use `URLForResource:withExtension:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `fileURLWithPath` to create a URL from a path.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `URLWithString` method and this method expects `URLString` to contain only characters that are allowed in a properly formed URL. All other characters must be properly percent escaped. Any percent-escaped characters are interpreted using UTF-8 encoding.

To create `NSURL` objects for file system paths, use `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` instead.

[Here is the referece of the Apple Developers Library Documentation for NSURL Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:)